# Problema al renderizar mi aplicación de react en iOs utilizando create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi aplicación de Reactjs, el cual es que no me está ejecutando el script que monta la app, esto quiere decir que no me está llegando al método de ReactDOM y no se muestra la app como tal en el navegador.

La app la cree con create-react-app pero también hice `npm run eject`.

Éste problema sólo existe en iOs, ya que en android y en pc funciona normalmente.

Probé tanto con Safari, como con Chrome.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './routes/App.jsx';
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {
      // console.log(registration.scope);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
    });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste algún cambio después del eject?

Comment: Ya pude corregir el problema, era un problema con Apollo Client, ya que la versión que tenia no era compatible con iOs.

Comment: tengo exactamente el mismo problema, mi app react funciona bien en todo excepto en safari ¿Podrías decirme porfa como lo solucionaste?.
te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias porbar colocando en el index.html de la carpeta public esto:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
```